# Ошибка в Retrofit2: Only one encoding annotation is allowed

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Использую `Retrofit2` для отправки файлов на сервер, `POST` запрос принимает два параметра `file` и `shared-with`, использую такой код:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Multipart
    @POST("shared-with")
    Call<RequestBody> sendFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                               @Field("shared-with") String sharedWith);
```

Получаю такую ошибку: `Only one encoding annotation is allowed`. Как правильно нужно переписать данный запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя смешивать FormUrlEncoded и Multipart

```
@Multipart
@POST("shared-with")
Call<RequestBody> sendFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                           @Part("shared-with") RequestBody sharedWith);
```

Comment: Спасибо. помогло!